# SessionFactory configuration in Servlet -context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

I am new to Spring+hibernate.I am using Spring+hibernate+postgresql database.
I created hibernate.cfg.xml through eclipse. I have given connection url,connection name, password,driver class. Next thing I am going to sessionFactory configuration in servlet.context.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.example" />

 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <!--<property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />-->
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate Transaction Manager -->
<beans:bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Activates annotation based transaction management -->
```

but still now could not autowired sessionFactory. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: What the exceptions you are getting ??

Answer (score 0):

You are missing hibernate.cfg.xml location in your sessionFactory bean, provide hibernate config location like this.

```
 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 <!--<property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />-->
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Also it's not a better choice to supply db username, password, url, Driver Etc.  in hibernate.cfg.xml file, Instead you can create a datasource bean and inject that bean to session factory like this :

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driver}" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="${db.jdbcurl}" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
 <!--<property name="schemaUpdate" value="true" />-->
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <beans:property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: Still now i am getting "Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Ljava/lang/String;I)" @prakash

Comment: which version of hibernate jars you are using

Comment: do you have jboss-logging.jar at your classpath / lib

Comment: using hibernate 5.1.0 and i have added jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar in classpath.

Comment: Yes this is the root cause, you need to downgrade it to Hibernate 4

Comment: add hibernate-core-4.3.6.Final.jar, hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.4.Final.jar, hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, hibernate-validator-4.3.2.Final.jar, jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR1.jar in your classpath, I have tested with these jars and it works fine  for me

Comment: Okay.. Please can you tell me the reason? is it not works in hibernate 5.1.0?